# Mysql: multiple column indexes, does the order of the multiple column index matter?

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, database-indexes

I'm trying to understand multiple-column indexes.

The question is:
**Does the order of the multiple column index matter?**

I have a table with columns A, B, C and D.

I execute a query:

```
SELECT A FROM table WHERE D='2' AND B='1' AND C='0' ;
```

Is there a difference in speed if I create only one multiple column index:

- B, C, D
- D, B, C

Or doesn't the order of the multiple column index matter?

Extra question:

**If I execute the following query, does it still benefit from the multiple column index?**

```
SELECT A, B FROM tablename WHERE D='2' AND C='0';
```

Why (not)?

Comment: Wow, my php-script used to take +/- 29 seconds to execute, and with mysql-indexes on multiple columns, it only takes +/- 0.34 seconds!!

That's +/- 85 times faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of the multi-column indexes doesn't matter. In other words following two queries are identical:

```
SELECT A FROM table WHERE D='2' AND B='1' AND C='0';
SELECT A FROM table WHERE B='1' AND D='2' AND C='0';
```

Your last query uses index [D, B, C] for `D` but not `C` as `B` isn't being used in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT A, B FROM tablename WHERE D='2' AND C='0';
```

This is due to the fact that first part (column B) of the index isn't used. You may find more details in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on.

Comment: And if I add another index, only on columns D and C?
So then I'd have 2 multiple column indexes, one on "C and D" and one on "B, C and D"
Or will that slow my query down instead?

Comment: That should speed up your last query and slow down your inserts a bit.

Comment: Ok, so I should only use it on large tables :-)
Thank you!

Comment: "Your last query doesn't use indexes" - That's not quite correct. `WHERE D='2' AND C='0'` *can* of course use the index on **(D,B,C)**.

Comment: @HannoBinder: that's true for `D` but not for `C`.

Comment: Of course. But still, the index can be used by the RDBMS to shorten the access path. How efficiently that can be depends on the relative selectivities of D and (B,C).

Comment: When I do an order by, is the index used then?
Example: WHERE D='2', B='1', C='0' ORDER BY B

Comment: Yes, in your example index would be used. That said, there are cases when `ORDER BY` [cannot](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) use indexes.